# Visual Composer adds </p><p> before and after table, how to remove?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I've added Visual Composer to my WordPress website. By adding a table there is a mysterious `< /p > < p >` in the first span and in the latest span from the table. I've tried this code to remove them, but without succes:

```
jQuery("span:contains('</p><p>')").each(function(){
    console.log('p tag gevonden');
     var str = "</p><p>";
     jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace(str,''));
});
```

From our friend 'inspect element' in Google Chrome, this is the html:

```
<td class="vc_table_cell"><span class="vc_table_content"></p><p>Stad</span></td>

<td style="font-size:14px;line-height:14px;" class="vc_table_cell" data-th="Beschikbaar"><span class="vc_table_content">Beschikbaar</p><p></span></td>
```

Comment: How about `jQuery("span > p").each`

Comment: did you tried something in wordpress native `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to fix the bug:

```
jQuery("span").each(function(){
 jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).html().replace('\&lt\;\/p\&gt\;',''));
 jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).html().replace('\&amp\;lt\;p\&amp\;gt\;',''));
 jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).html().replace('\&lt\;',''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Get the span, loop through the contents, remove any `'<p></p>'` element.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6LLmzzaz/)

```
$('span').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.tagName === 'P';
}).remove();
```

---

Update: It seems your `<p></p>` actually are text and don't work like actual elements.

```
$('span').contents().map(function(index, value){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/[#\<\/p\>]/g, '');
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/5pz2hbpw/)

Comment: Are you calling your script before the page finish loading? It's quite possible your script runs first, and then visual composer finishes adding your '<p></p>'

Comment: I'm calling my script the correct way. I found out the p-tags are in the html-output as '&lt;/p&gt;'

Comment: Can you update your question and add the HTML span structure?

Comment: Updated again, the p-tags are normal p-tags when I use your code.